# Newspaper and Video Channel in Esperanto

Tags: learning

Is there a main newspaper in Esperanto, something like Le Monde for French or Süddeutsche Zeitung for German?

Also, where could I find videos in Esperanto, for example, a YouTube channel or another website? The main feature is that the videos contain conversations fully in Esperanto and that the language is spoken fluently.

Answer (score 8):

Newspapers in Esperanto: [Katalogo de Esperanta retenhavo/Periodaĵoj kaj radio](https://eo.wikibooks.org/wiki/Katalogo_de_Esperanta_retenhavo/Perioda%C4%B5oj_kaj_radio), [Novaĵoj en Esperanto](http://esperanto.net/eo/novajoj-en-esperanto/), [La Hodiaŭa Ĵurnalo](https://lahodiauajurnalo.wordpress.com/), [Libera Folio](http://www.liberafolio.org/).

Videos in Esperanto: [Tubaro](https://tubaro.aperu.net/), [Evildea](https://www.youtube.com/user/Evildela/videos), [Esperanto VBlogo](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCL5omL_KmBWS6eXhRcBuBsQ/videos), [Torina Esperanto-Centro](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMIsshthraGZAE2e82YpW4A/videos?sort=dd&view=0&shelf_id=0), [Tejo](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1cW8y4NncmbRr6zD5IO8xw), [E@I](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbijDBZxl2tnVCFH0ECNaWQ/featured), [UEAviva](https://www.youtube.com/user/UEAviva/), [Federación EsperantoES](https://www.youtube.com/user/esesperanto/videos).

Answer (score 7):

#### Newspaper

The [Esperanto-USA Retbutiko](http://retbutiko.esperanto-usa.org/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=1002_1003) has several newspapers & magazines available for subscription.

- [La Gazeto](http://retbutiko.esperanto-usa.org/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1002_1003&products_id=18327):

*Independent magazine published in France by a group of well known Esperantists. Excellent Esperanto and geared more toward cultural expression than the Esperanto movement. Illustrated 32 pages (245x165) per issue. 6 issues per subscription sent by airmail. Available throughout the year.*

- [Monato](http://retbutiko.esperanto-usa.org/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1002_1003&products_id=18338):

*Monthly magazine of general international interest published in Belgium. articles on current affairs and in-depth reports on different parts of the world plus various special columns. Although in Esperanto, it does not concern itself with the Esperanto movement. It is more like a genuinely international Time or Newsweek. Illustrated.*

#### Magazine

It's a magazine, not a newspaper, but [ILEI (Internacia Ligo de Esperantistaj Instruistoj)](http://www.ilei.info/) hosts a [HUGE PDF archive](https://www.eventoj.hu/juna-amiko/) of the *Juna Amiko* magazine in a publicly available Google Drive folder. The magazine is written in simple Esperanto and is geared toward younger readers. It has issues from 1972 to present (minus a 2-year waiting period to encourage subscriptions). You can subscribe to the magazine with a UEA subsidiary or directly with ILEI (I couldn't figure how to subscribe directly though). Here's the info from the [ILEI magazine site](http://www.ilei.info/revuoj/):

"Perantoj en trideko da landoj akceptas abonojn, eblas tra la abonservo de UEA ĝin mendi, ankaŭ rekte ĉe la kasisto de ILEI."

#### Youtube

There is a ["movie" adaptation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXjmX2jipQ4) of *Gerda Mapaleris!* from the group [Imagu Filmoj](https://imagufilmoj.wordpress.com/) on Youtube. The audio quality leaves much to be desired, but it includes Esperanto subtitles. The film is entirely in Esperanto.

Answer (score 5):

I would start with [Monato](http://www.esperanto.be/fel/mon/) and [Esperanto Variety Show](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXnT_KZNsQw-MX8Q8gJQDgw)

Answer (score 2):

Le Monde diplomatique
legeblas rete

https://eo.mondediplo.com/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. I too wish for a CNN International style online news service in Esperanto. But, someones with resources and money will have to make one first. Maybe some day.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. I wonder if you have read the other answers. Perhaps you could explain how you came to the conclusion that the answer is _no_ despite all of the other answers giving examples of newspapers and YouTube channels.